# JQuery Validator Find the previous element

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am having a problem with a small jquery code. I am trying to insert error message into span but I think I cannot locate the span correctly.

here is my html code...

```
<div>İsim <span style="font-size:9px;color:red"></span></div><div style="line-height: 3px">&nbsp;</div><div><input type="text" id="txt_isim" onkeypress="$('#txt_isim_4').val($('#txt_isim').val());" onKeyUp="$('#txt_isim_4').val($('#txt_isim').val());" style="width: 200px" class="blue_input required" minlength="3" /></div><div style="line-height: 6px">&nbsp;</div>
```

here is the jquery code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txt_isim").validate({
            submitHandler: function () {
                return false;
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.appendTo(element.prev().parent("span"));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am trying to validate "txt_isim" and display the error message in the span. but I think I couldnt locate the span with PREV() and PARENT() functions. What is wrong with my code?

NOTE: If I give an ID to span and put $('#id_span'), It works perfectly. But I need to do it without ID. Please help

Comment: in which span? is it `<span style="font-size:9px;color:red"></span>`

Comment: Yes,I want to write into the  <span style="font-size:9px;color:red"></span>

Comment: will you be able to add a `class` attribute instead of id

Comment: well, but I am going to write this piece of code so many times, so I think I should locate previous  span. Am I wrong?

Comment: I would recommend you to add a container for the repeating piece like `<div class="field"><div>Isim  <span class="error-handler" style="font-size:9px;color:red"></span></div><div style="line-height: 3px">&nbsp;</div><div> <input type="text" id="txt_isim" onkeypress="$('#txt_isim_4').val($('#txt_isim').val());" onKeyUp="$('#txt_isim_4').val($('#txt_isim').val());" style="width: 200px" class="blue_input required" minlength="3" /></div><div style="line-height: 6px">&nbsp;</div></div>` then `error.appendTo(element.closest('.field').parent(".error-handler"));`

Comment: If I do this, How am I supposed the find te span?

Comment: `error.appendTo(element.closest('.field').parent(".error-handler"));`

Comment: sorry `error.appendTo(element.closest('.field').find(".error-handler"))`

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t3vfj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txt_isim").validate({
            submitHandler: function () {
                return false;
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.appendTo(element.parent().prev().prev().children('span'))
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hkkyp/1/

But this is not the secure way, because it depends on your html structure, and if you add for example another element between your divs, it will not work anymore.

I would prefer to add a class to your span, and than use the class selector to add your message.

Comment: add the class="error" to your span, and then do `error.appendTo($(".error"));`

Comment: But I am going to have this piece of code many times. Therefore, I need to locate it in the specific div

Comment: I updated the answer with the full code, for me, this works, try copy paste it

Answer (score 0):

In you case I would recommend you to have a container element for the multiple parts related to the single field

```
<div class="field">
    <div>Isim 
        <span class="error-handler" style="font-size:9px;color:red"></span>
    </div>
    <div style="line-height: 3px">&nbsp;</div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="txt_isim" onkeypress="$('#txt_isim_4').val($('#txt_isim').val());" onKeyUp="$('#txt_isim_4').val($('#txt_isim').val());" style="width: 200px" class="blue_input required" minlength="3" />
    </div>
    <div style="line-height: 6px">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Then in `errorPlacement`

```
error.appendTo(element.closest('.field').find(".error-handler"))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t3vfj/)